# WSO2 IS 5.0 sp1 Session Management

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have a scenario wherein multiple service providers enrolled in WSO2 IS 5.0 SP1 are residing in different J2EE containers like tomcat and jboss. These service providers form  the part of SAML SSO/SLO. All these applications are having different session timeout. Is there a way to manage these session timeouts through WSO2 IS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some useful information : http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/02/12/sp-idp-session-time-out-with-saml2-sso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no. There's no mechanism for IdP to directly manage an SP's session timeout.

Let's dig a little deeper...

Usually there are two sessions getting created upon a successful SAML communication. An IdP session and an SP session. Timeouts for those sessions are managed by the respective parties that own the sessions.

i.e. IdP session timeout is managed by the IdP, whilst the SP session timeout is managed by that particular SP.

The only way an IdP or an SP can interfere with each other's session timeout logic is via Single Logout Requests (the requirements/reasons for an SLO request is beyond the scope of this question). Then again, considering an SLO request from IdP to SP, it's up to the SP to actually terminate the session, IdP can only ask.

Comment: Thanks Dulanja. I came across this post http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/02/12/sp-idp-session-time-out-with-saml2-sso/

Comment: Thanks Dulanja for your response. That answers my question. However I came across this post http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/02/12/sp-idp-session-time-out-with-saml2-sso/   It explains various scenarios of session management. Does this hold good? I think I need to handle SAML2 SSO Passive requests from SP so that the IDP timeout doesn't happen when there are active SP.